# Infer windows 7/8/10 ISOs official URLs from Linux

Tags: linux, iso

How to infer windows 7/8/10 ISOs official URLs from Linux and download them ?

I only have Linux on my system and hence cannot run the [Windows ISO downloader](https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-iso-download-tool) to do so.

How can I do it ?

Comment: You can use Google to get the URLs to the ISO files and go from there.

Comment: Do you 'only' need an iso file? Do you know how to make a Windows installer from it?

Comment: @sudodus I will use [ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net) for the rest :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going to either:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

and changing the user agent to something else than Windows (Blackberry BB10, Nexus 6P) worked for me.

- **With Google Chrome:** open the development tools with Ctrl + Shift + i, open the mobile mode with Ctrl + Shift + m, select a device (e.g. Nexus 6P) then reload the page.
- **With Mozilla Firefox:** open the adaptive view with Ctrl + Shift + m, select a device (e.g. Google Nexus 7) then reload the page. To be able to use the form fields, deactivate the simulation of touch events by clicking on the pointer icon.
- **With Microsoft Edge:** open the development tools (F12) then select a Microsoft Lumia device in the Emulation tab.

Windows 7 Ultimate can be directly downloaded from Microsoft's servers:

- Link: https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/1/9/5195A765-3A41-4A72-87D8-200D897CBE21/7601.24214.180801-1700.win7sp1_ldr_escrow_CLIENT_ULTIMATE_x64FRE_en-us.iso
- SHA-256: dec04cbd352b453e437b2fe9614b67f28f7c0b550d8351827bc1e9ef3f601389

Comment: If you're using linux anyway, it'll throw you to the 'correct' ISO download

Comment: @geckoflume Thanks for answer. Copying the Microsoft Official ISO URLs and paste it to `wget` or `aria2c` also worked fine for the download.